# Jquery click on one of visible elements handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When my modal window is visible, when i click on #screen or on #loading_modal i need to hide this div's, but how can i do that, and how to write it correctly, now my code is not working, but also i have same for two objects (#screen, #loading_modal).... I'm new in js, how to refactor this code, and make it working properly... ?

```
  if ($('#screen').is(':visible')) {
    $("#screen").click(function() {    
      $('#screen').hide();
      $('#loading_modal').hide();  
    });
     $("#loading_modal").click(function() {    
      $('#screen').hide();
      $('#loading_modal').hide();  
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the `if` statement here, you can simply use:

```
$('element:visible').click(function() { ... })
```

So:

```
$("#screen:visible").click(function() {    
    $(this).hide();
    $('#loading_modal').hide();  
});
 $("#loading_modal:visible").click(function() {    
    $('#screen').hide();
    $(this).hide();  
});
```

If the functions are going to perform identical tasks, you can simply use:

```
$("#screen:visible, #loading_modal:visible").click(function() {    
    $('#screen').hide();
    $('#loading_modal').hide();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly I think you need to put the check for visibility inside the click handlers like so:

```
$("#screen").click(function() {    
    if ($('#screen').is(':visible')) {
        $('#screen').hide();
        $('#loading_modal').hide();  
    }
});
$("#loading_modal").click(function() {    
    if ($('#screen').is(':visible')) {
        $('#screen').hide();
        $('#loading_modal').hide();  
    }
});
```

Comment: No need for the `.is(':visible')` check, you can simply `$("#screen:visible").click()`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you are doing wrong. you can check the Condition in click event. once the click event fired. 
put `if` conditon in side the click event handler

```
$("#screen").click(function() {    
    if ($('#screen').is(':visible')) {
        $('#screen').hide();
        $('#loading_modal').hide();  
    }
});
$("#loading_modal").click(function() {    
    if ($('#screen').is(':visible')) {
        $('#screen').hide();
        $('#loading_modal').hide();  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just refactor your code to look like this

```
$("#screen,#loading_modal").click(function() { 
      $('#screen,#loading_modal').hide();       
});
```

There's no need to check if it's visible

If it's dynamically created, you will need to delegate or bind after creation of the elements

```
$('body').on('click',"#screen,#loading_modal",function() { 
      $('#screen,#loading_modal').hide();       
});
```

Comment: @brabertaser1992 if they're not visible you can't click on them anyways.. so there really is not reason to check for visiblility

Comment: What @wirey is saying is that if the elements aren't visible the user will not be able to click on them anyway. In case you're unsure: `.hide()` sets the CSS `display` attribute to `none`, **not** `visibility` to `hidden`. With `display:none;` they won't appear on the page at all. If you *do* need to check for visibility, check my answer below.